# hadoop cluster is not running map reduce jobs - issue with scheduler

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

(this is a follow-up on a discussion I had regarding an earlier question I had on this matter)

I set up a small Hadoop cluster following [these](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/spinning-up-a-free-hadoop-cluster-step-by-step-c406d56bae42) instructions but using Hadoop version 2.7.4. The cluster seems to work OK, but I cannot run mapreduce jobs. In particular, when trying the following

```
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.4.jar randomwriter outdenter code here
```

the job prints

```
17/11/27 16:35:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at 
ec2-yyy.eu-central-
1.compute.amazonaws.com/xxx:8032
Running 0 maps.

Job started: Mon Nov 27 16:35:22 UTC 2017

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at 
ec2-yyy.eu-central-
1.compute.amazonaws.com/xxx:8032


17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for 
job: job_1511799491035_0006

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application 
application_1511799491035_0006

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: 
http://ec2-yyy.eu-central-
1.compute.amazonaws.com:8088/proxy/application_1511799491035_0006/

17/11/27 16:35:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: 
job_1511799491035_0006
```

and never gets past this state.

In the job tracker, it says

```
ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and 
register with RM.
```

I then looked into the log files where I found

```
2017-11-27 13:50:29,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource capacity-scheduler.xml at file:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml
2017-11-27 13:50:29,252 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc mb per queue for root is undefined
2017-11-27 13:50:29,252 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc vcore per queue for root is undefined
2017-11-27 13:50:29,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root, capacity=1.0, asboluteCapacity=1.0, maxCapacity=1.0, asboluteMaxCapacity=1.0, state=RUNNING, acls=ADMINISTER_QUEUE:*SUBMIT_APP:*, labels=*, reservationsContinueLooking=true
2017-11-27 13:50:29,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Initialized parent-queue root name=root, fullname=root
2017-11-27 13:50:29,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc mb per queue for root.default is undefined
2017-11-27 13:50:29,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc vcore per queue for root.default is undefined
```

which suggest that there is a problem with the capacity scheduler. The file `capacity-scheduler.xml` looks as follows:

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
      Maximum number of applications that can be pending and running.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>0.1</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run 
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
    <description>
      The ResourceCalculator implementation to be used to compare 
      Resources in the scheduler.
      The default i.e. DefaultResourceCalculator only uses Memory while
      DominantResourceCalculator uses dominant-resource to compare 
      multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
    <value>default</value>
    <description>
      The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Default queue user limit a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
    <description>
      The maximum capacity of the default queue. 
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can submit jobs to the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can administer jobs on the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay</name>
    <value>40</value>
    <description>
      Number of missed scheduling opportunities after which the CapacityScheduler 
      attempts to schedule rack-local containers. 
      Typically this should be set to number of nodes in the cluster, By default is setting 
      approximately number of nodes in one rack which is 40.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>
      A list of mappings that will be used to assign jobs to queues
      The syntax for this list is [u|g]:[name]:[queue_name][,next mapping]*
      Typically this list will be used to map users to queues,
      for example, u:%user:%user maps all users to queues with the same name
      as the user.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      If a queue mapping is present, will it override the value specified
      by the user? This can be used by administrators to place jobs in queues
      that are different than the one specified by the user.
      The default is false.
    </description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

I would be grateful for any hints on how to approach this?.

Thanks
c14

Comment: OK. Thanks. I added the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing fine with Cluster configuration but When it comes to Job execution, RAM provided by t2.micro instance is not enough to run the MapReduce jobs, so better use bigger instances for cluster creation and job execution

Comment: Hi I am not using t2.mico instance, but m4.xlarge. I have chosen a harddisk of only 20GB per worker could this be an issue?